# ASP.NET 5 / Core 1 Dependency Injection: Bad design or bad documentation?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm reading through the [ASP.NET 5 docs](http://docs.asp.net/) and was choking on the chapter of dependency injection.

I am recommended to write my controllers like so:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    private readonly MyService _myService;

    public MyController(MyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // use _myService
    }
}
```

The short and direct version is discouraged:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var myService = (MyService)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(MyService));
    }   
}
```

[The given reason](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#request-services-and-application-services) is because allegedly the recommended version...

> [...] yields classes that are easier to test (see Testing) and are more loosely coupled.

The linked testing chapter doesn't shed any light on this weird statement.

I didn't look at the sources, but I assume whatever constructs the controller is using `HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService` itself to deliver the dependency? Clearly a test can setup a different implementation for testing, and clearly *that* is the whole point of a DI framework, right?

The colossus `(MyService)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(MyService))` is bad enough, but a small helper could fix that (was a simple `Get<MyService>()` really so hard?).

But that this excessive clutter is recommended *for basically every controller and more* is disturbing.

It's all the more puzzling as there already is a Microsoft DI framework with a proper usage, MEF:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [Import]
    private MyService _myService;

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // use _myService
    }
}
```

Why not at least just take that one? What's going on here?

Comment: Not suitable type of question on SO. Please read the FAQ/Help Center before posting. Primary opinion based are not the right type of question for SO. Just a sentence to your "question": Your version hides the dependencies and during a unit test it's impossible to know which dependencies a class has, whereas constructor you see it plus your types depend on a specific container now whereas constructor doesn't.

Comment: It's just bad documentation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a ASP.NET Core specific solution. This is how just about every DI framework works. The most common approach is to have all the dependencies of a controller as constructor parameters. This makes it clear what services the controller uses. There are multiple alternative solutions, but the basic idea stays the same and there are multiple pros and cons to them.

> Clearly a test can setup a different implementation for testing, and clearly that is the whole point of a DI framework, right?

This line isn't clear to me. What do you think the 'whole point of a DI framework ' is? This line suggest you only use it so you can use a different implementation for testing.

> But that this excessive clutter is recommended for basically every controller and more is disturbing.

Excessive clutter? What if I want to use MyService in two (or more) functions? Should I use this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var myService = (MyService)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(MyService));
    }

    public IActionResult Index2()
    {
        var myService = (MyService)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(MyService));
    }
}
```

Or should I opt for the solution where I set it up in the constructor? Seems like an obvious choice to me. In such a small example it may look like clutter, but add 10 lines of code to it and you'll barely notice a small constructor and some variable declarations.

You can use it while testing. It's a way to quickly grab something from the container when you need it, but it should certainly not be part of the actual code. You're simply hiding the dependency from sight.

At last you suggest property injection. This is a valid solution. But an often used argument against it is that it hides the dependency. If you define it as a parameter in the constructor you can't hide it. Besides, a lot of DI frameworks don't even have support for property or method injection because of this.

If you want to use MEF in your project you are free to do so. But it should, in my opinion, not be the default DI framework for ASP.NET. What's available right now is more than sufficient to do most tasks. If you need more functionality you can always use a different DI framework like [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.io/) or [AutoFac](http://autofac.org/).

In the end it all comes down to what works for you. But stating this is either bad design or bad documentation is just wrong. You are of course free to prove me wrong on this. You could improve the ASP.NET documentation and/or would prove that the concept of inversion of control is wrong and suggest a better solution.

Comment: I accept the point that it's tradition. I only knew MEF, so it was ASP.NET I blamed. I still hold that everything that produces clutter like that is bad design, but I understand that this is an opinion as valid as yours.

Comment: Can you change "Entity Framework" to MEF in your answer? For some reason my edits appear to get rejected.